# Are task dependencies always run in a specific order with rake?

Tags: ruby, rake

I have the following example which is based on the structure i want my rakefile to use:

```
task :default do
    puts 'Tasks you can run: dev, stage, prod'
end

task :dev => [:init,:devrun,:clean]
task :devrun do
    puts 'Dev stuff'
end

task :stage => [:init,:stagerun,:clean]
task :stagerun do
    puts 'Staging stuff'
end

task :prod => [:init,:prodrun,:clean]
task :prodrun do
    puts 'Production stuff'
end

task :init do
    puts 'Init...'
end

task :clean do
    puts 'Cleanup'
end
```

Will the tasks always be run in the same order? I read somewhere that they wouldn't, and somewhere else that they would, so i'm not sure.

Or if you can suggest a better way to do what i'm trying to achieve (eg have a common init and cleanup step surrounding a depending-upon-environment step), that'd also be good.

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

From the Rake source code:

```
# Invoke all the prerequisites of a task.
def invoke_prerequisites(task_args, invocation_chain) # :nodoc:
  @prerequisites.each { |n|
    prereq = application[n, @scope]
    prereq_args = task_args.new_scope(prereq.arg_names)
    prereq.invoke_with_call_chain(prereq_args, invocation_chain)
  }
end
```

So it appears that the code normally just iterates the array and runs the prerequisite tasks sequentially.

However:

```
# Declare a task that performs its prerequisites in parallel. Multitasks does
# *not* guarantee that its prerequisites will execute in any given order
# (which is obvious when you think about it)
#
# Example:
#   multitask :deploy => [:deploy_gem, :deploy_rdoc]
#
def multitask(args, &block)
  Rake::MultiTask.define_task(args, &block)
end
```

So you are right, both can be true, but order can only be off if you prefix your task with `multitask`  It looks like regular tasks are run in order.